# Attaching the Script debugger to process '[XXXX] IEXPLORE.EXE' on machine 'NAME' failed

Tags: visual-studio-2008

Few days ago I started getting the following error when I try to run/debug my web application using F5 in Visual Studio 2008:

*Attaching the Script debugger to process '[XXXX] IEXPLORE.EXE' on machine 'NAME' failed. The process does not have sufficient privileges to be debugged.*

I am using Visual Studio 2008, IE8 and Visual Studio Development Server(as my web server)

I did look around and couldn't find much on the web!!

Comment: Got exactly the same problem myself, also just started in the last couple of days. Only difference is I'm using IIS.

Comment: I have the same problem, but with VS2010 and IIS.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had the same problem, run this command fixed my problem:

**regsvr32.exe "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\VS7Debug\msdbg2.dll"**

the key point of running this must start Command Prompt under '**Run as administrartor**'

Comment: I think this is a more accurate answer!

Answer (score 1):

Here how I fixed this:

Start, run: regsvr32 c:\windows\system32\oleaut32.dll

Answer (score 1):

This works but it is:

```
regsvr32 c:\windows\system32\oleaut32.dll
```

not

```
regsrv32 c:\windows\system32\oleaut32.dll
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you register the dll from an elevated command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

Having exited all instances of Internet Explorer (but not VS), I tried

```
regsvr32.exe "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\VS7Debug\msdbg2.dll"
```

but got an error message LoadLibrary(%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\VS7Debug\msdbg2.dll) failed - 0x0000007e.

After checking the file system I found the DLL and tried this:

```
regsvr32.exe "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\VS7Debug\msdbg2.dll"
```

which fixed it.