# VS2012 Lost JavaScript Debugger

Tags: javascript, debugging, visual-studio-2012

About 2 weeks ago, I lost the ability to debug JavaScript. I have Windows 8 Pro, IE 10 and Visual Studio 2012 with all updates installed. Until that time, I had no issues - now it does it on every project.

The message I get is...

"No Source Available. The current code thread is not currently running code or the call stack could not be obtained"

Any suggestions as to how I get my JavaScript debugger back? I have already tried do a repair and a re-install with no success.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Does debugging still work if you manually insert a `debugger` statement in your script?

Comment: How you try to debug? At what point you see the error message you mentioned?

Comment: In IE, it will sometimes stop on debugger;, but not always - when it does, I will get the error as it continues or it will merely pay no attention to the regular F9 breakpoints . In Chrome, it will stop, but I'm not familiar enough with the Chrome debugger to actually step through.

To debug, I am doing exactly what I was doing a few weeks ago before the problem happened. F9 to set breakpoints and 'Debug' as the mode.

Answer (score 17):

I had the same problem using VS 2012 after installing IE 10 on Win 7 64bit.  I tried several things including "fixing" VS, uninstalling/reinstalling IE10.  I couldn't get VS to be set breakpoints in javascript for anything.

What finally worked was in VS 2012 I clicked on the "Play" toolbar button (little green arrow pointing right) and had two items listed for Internet Explorer, one being the default.  At the bottom of the drop down from that button, I selected "Browse With" which brought up a dialogue box which let me delete one of the two IE's.  I also selected Chrome and then back to IE which may have had an impact.  In any case, after doing that, everything is working again.

Comment: I wonder if your case had to do with the 64 vs 86 versions of IE?  I've seen problems with 64 bit IE not properly running plugins / activex's.  Maybe you removed your 64 bit version?

At any rate, I only have 1 in my Browse with window.  I did try running both IE versions to no avail.

Comment: I found 2 'Internet Explorer' entries in my list.  One was set to default.  I changed to have the other one set as default instead.  It started to work again and the duplicate went away by itself.

Comment: Thanks very much!  This solved my problem and I am back in business!  :)

Comment: This happened to me after installing IE10. I noticed the two "Internet Explorer" entries, but didn't think much of it. For me to be able to remove one of them, I had to open the dialog as you said, then set something other than IE as the default (I chose Chrome), then delete *both* of the IE entries. When I closed the dialog via Cancel, the drop-down menu still showed one IE and now script debugging works! I tried deleting just one, but the extra entry still remained. Perhaps you have to delete the *right* one, but it's impossible to tell which is which.

Answer (score 1):

I kept playing and removed KB2781514, did a repair on VS2012 and got the JavaScript debugger back - all seems to now work, but I'm really afraid to install that update.

I also turned off automatic updates and will make sure that I set a restore point before adding most any future update.

Comment: I've got same problem as yours on win8 pro + ie10 + vs2012 update1, but uninstall KB2781514 and repair take me some 40 minutes and DOESN'T fix the problem. The same problem also on my win7 sp1 + ie10 + vs2012 update1 when at work.

Answer (score 1):

Try the solution form this post - 
[VS2010 and IE10 Attaching the Script debugger to process iexplore.exe failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13421797/vs2010-and-ie10-attaching-the-script-debugger-to-process-iexplore-exe-failed/15168080#15168080)

- Close IE
- In elevated cmd prompt run this command:

  regsvr32.exe "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\VS7Debug\msdbg2.dll"

  or

  %ProgramFiles% on a 32-bit OS

  Restart VS & IE.
  I restarted the machine to be sure.

Comment: This worked for me with Win 7 Ult x64, IE 10, VS 2012.
On Win 8, it worked fine from the get go.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this same problem with VS2010 and VS2012 on WIN7 + IE10 CTP back in December last year. I hoped this problem was solved in the RTM version of IE10, today I found out it was not (and probably because it's not a IE10 problem).

Checkout my answer in the link below, maybe it's working for you as well.

[VS2010 and IE10 Attaching the Script debugger to process iexplore.exe failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13421797/vs2010-and-ie10-attaching-the-script-debugger-to-process-iexplore-exe-failed/15373837#15373837)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error with Windows8 + IE10 + VS2012 Update 1, but today I was update vs2012 with Update 2 and the problem is solved.

[VS2012 Update 2 here](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/esn/downloads#d-visual-studio-2012-update)