# I can debug Javascript in IE10 with VS2010 if I manually attach debugger, can I automate it?

Tags: visual-studio-debugging, internet-explorer-10

So I just updated to IE10. When I try to debug my web app's javascript, my breakpoints are all just outlines with a little triangle and say in the tooltip:

> The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded
>   for this document.

IE10 is started when I start debugging and it goes to the website like IE9 always did. If, in VS 2010, I go to `Debug > Attach to Process...` and select the iexplore.exe process, as my javascript executes it will hit and stop at breakpoints like it always would with IE9 and everything is peachy until I kill IE10 and start debugging again.

I've made sure that Javascript Debugging is enabled in IE10 and any "solutions" I find online all say to uninstall/reinstall VS2010/IE10 and see if that helps. I already know that VS2010 is capable of debugging, it's just not attaching the debugger properly. How can I fix this so that debugger attaches properly and will hit breakpoints and exhibit the usual behaviour?

Answer (score 3):

Another [StackOverflow Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13421797/vs2010-and-ie10-attaching-the-script-debugger-to-process-iexplore-exe-failed) recommends installing VS2012 (any version) and that should fix your issue when debugging JavaScript in IE10 with VS2010.

Comment: Ultimately, for many reasons, I want to get all of my coworkers on it. But we all have to make the jump at the same time because we all collaborate on the same project. Until I can convince them to do that, I'm looking for a way where I can stay with VS2010.

Answer (score 0):

This may fix JavaScript debugging issue in IE10:

- Close Internet Explorer
- Press start and type CMD
- Run one of these commands in command prompt

32-bit OS

```
regsvr32.exe "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\VS7Debug\msdbg2.dll"
```

64-bit OS

```
regsvr32.exe "%ProgramFiles%\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\VS7Debug\msdbg2.dll"
```

Comment: No change. Still behaves the way I described.

Answer (score 0):

There is another thread on this issue, as Elijah mentions, and this answer is probably more appropriate there, but that thread is closed to me because I'm a new poster. Corey has already mentioned that he can't install VS2012 at this time, but it may be useful to others.

I experienced this same problem after updating to IE10. I already had VS2010 and VS2012 with Update 1 installed, and none of the recommended fixes (including the msdbg2.dll registration) worked for me. What fixed my problem was to reapply Update 1 for VS2012, choosing the "Repair" option. I can now debug javascript in VS2010 again.

Comment: I didn't think about installing VS2012 along side VS2010. I may be able to get away with that at work.

Comment: VS2010 and VS2012 coexist pretty happily in my experience. It's supposed to be possible to move between the versions with the same project, although I haven't tried it. Once you start using VS2012, though - particularly with javascript - you'll probably not want to go back.

Comment: In my personal use I solely use VS2012. My hands are tied however at work. I think today I'll try to move everybody over...