# Disable message if application is running from Visual Web Developer Express 2010 using IE10

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, internet-explorer, asp.net-mvc-2

ASP .NET 3.5 MVC2 application is running from Visual Web Developer Express 2010 by pressing F5

All pages are served from localhost.

Default browser is Internet Explorer 10. after clicking in some links in application message

> *Attaching the Script debugger to process '[9376] iexplore.exe' on machine 'DELL2' failed. A debugger is already attached.*

appears in Web Developer. After clicking ok and clicking on some links in web application, this message appears again and again.

How to disable this message ?

This message starts to occur if browser was upgraded to Internet Explorer 10 using Windows Update.

If browser was Internet Explorer 9 this message never appears.

OS is Windows 7 x64.

**Update**

I applied changes from answer and closed Web Developer and IE 10:
I added INTERACTIVE user and checked Allow as shown in image below. System user with Allow
permission already exists.
Problem persist.
Link referenced to answer applies to Windows 2000 only but I have windows 7.

How to fix this ?

[image: dcomconfig]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start  commandprompt (run as admin) and run the following command:

regsvr32.exe "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\VS7Debug\msdbg2.dll

Problem solved!

Answer (score 0):

You may try this
open `dcomcnfg`, go to the properties page for Component Services | Computers | My Computer, go to the Default COM Security page, under "Access Permissions" click "Edit Default" and make sure that the local SYSTEM and INTERACTIVE users have "Access Permission" with the "Allow" checkbox checked.
It is a known issue as describe [here](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;Q274696)

Comment: Thank you. I applied your suggestions but problem persists. I updated question.

Answer (score 0):

To supplement Dennis's answer, in hope that it will help others who have tried it (and similar solutions posted around the Internet) to no avail:

In some cases, there is an additional step you must take (which I have not seen mentioned anywhere yet, including [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13421797/vs2010-and-ie10-attaching-the-script-debugger-to-process-iexplore-exe-failed)). Before running the "regsvr32.exe [...]" command to register msdb2.dll, you must first **unregister** the DLL, otherwise the registration will have no effect.

In other words, you must run both of the commands below (not just the second one) from an administrative command prompt in order to get rid of the error message:

```
regsvr32.exe /u "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\VS7Debug\msdbg2.dll"

regsvr32.exe "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\VS7Debug\msdbg2.dll"
```

This was the only solution that worked for me (with VS2010 Ultimate + 64-bit Windows 7 Professional).