# Debugging Classic asp Visual Studio 2008 IIS 8

Tags: visual-studio-2008, asp-classic, visual-studio-debugging, iis-8

Things I've done:
On both the default website and my virtual folder in IIS Manager

-Enabled Parent Paths

-Set Enable Server Side Debugging to be True

Set Breakpoints in my code by
1) F9
2) Using the Stop command
3) Purposefully put mispelled commands in my VBScript to force the debugger to attach

I've then tried starting the website without debugging and attaching to W3wp.exe/ DLLHost.exe

Have also tried running the website in visual studio in debug mode

Is there something I'm missing or worth trying?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was almost there but when I went to attach to process, selecting w3wp.exe, I needed select the code types I was trying to debug and make sure the Script checkbox was selected

Answer (score 0):

Try setting "send errors to browser" to TRUE in your application pool, and if that still doesn't work "Enable client-side debugging" to TRUE.

Also, I've seen some some issues on SO lately involving the debugger not kicking in when the client is IE10 (which is weird).
The solution there was to change a registry setting. It seems that installing IE10 messes up the link between the debugger and ASP. Maybe IIS8 does the same. Here is some more info, maybe it helps you:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/yash/archive/2007/09/20/debugger-not-working.aspx
[VS2010 and IE10 Attaching the Script debugger to process iexplore.exe failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13421797/vs2010-and-ie10-attaching-the-script-debugger-to-process-iexplore-exe-failed)

Another solution suggested (besides the registry setting) was to install VS2012 (the free edition is enough) to restore the link between the debugger and the server.

HTH.
Erik

Comment: Thanks Erik. I had already enabled client-side debugging and send errors to browser which i should have mentioned. I have a feeling it could be IE 10 related up to now and interesting to read your post. I've been running in compatability mode and tried the registry fix in the post you linked to but no difference. I have visual studio 2012 premium installed but upgrading is a last resort I've been told

Comment: At this stage I'd be happy to use any debugger so if anyone knows any 3rd party free debuggers I could use that would be an option