# Debugging Classic ASP Windows 8/IIS 8 VS2010/VS2012

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, windows-8, asp-classic

Moved over to Win8 to do Metro development, but need to support some Classic ASP code.

On windows 7/IIS6  could debug the Classic ASP code with VS2008/2010, no problems.

First time trying it on Win8/IIS8 and having no luck get this started.

In Win7/IIS6, start VS2010, Attached debugging to w3wp.exe (running VS2010 in administrator mode), debugger is attached and can see the Classic ASP code.

In Win8/IIS8, start VS2010, Attached debugging to w3wp.exe (running VS2010 in administrator mode), debugger is attached and I cannot see the Classic ASP code.

Other observation is under Win7, the w3wp.exe type is Script/Managed(v2...), x64

under Win8 the w3wp.exe type is x86.

Can anyone help?

Comment: did you already check this previous SO post ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15573322 (and the referenced SO post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13421797)

Answer (score 1):

as stated [here](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/770786/just-in-time-debugging-operation-attempted-is-not-supported#) it could be a problem with this registry key. for me the problems were solved by changing that registry key to 8.

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\AppID\\{E62A7A31-6025-408E-87F6-81AEB0DC9347}
```

set AppIDFlags from 28 to 8 (not to 20 as stated in the original Workaround by microsoft).

after i changed that registry key i was able to debug classic asp on IIS8 under win8 with vs2010 and vs2012. furthermore the use of the vbscipt keyword "stop" is possible after the change. the JIT Debugger pops up just like under win7/iis7