# Vs2012/vs2010, ie10.. why is the startup of a new debuggin session so slow?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-debugging

To start with, I blamed the slow startup on this problem:

[VS2010 and IE10 Attaching the Script debugger to process iexplore.exe failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13421797/vs2010-and-ie10-attaching-the-script-debugger-to-process-iexplore-exe-failed)

But after I fixed that, it still takes a really long time to start up a new debugging session... long enough to make you want to skip debugging.. that's not acceptable.

It's so long I feel like something is timing out before it actually starts IE and brings up the page.

Does anyone have any idea why and how to fix it?

It happening in vs2010 and vs2012..

Thanks,

Eric-

Answer (score 0):

I often have this problem, usually after a couple of times of debugging, it turns to very slow to start up again.

What I do is to open task manager and kill the alive **Webdev.Webserver40.EXE**  process which is not supposed to be there after you stop a debug.

Comment: I looked that process is not there, but it's still running upper slow.. no web.* process at all.