# Not hitting debugger point in included files in div element

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, debugging

I have Page1.aspx page which has Page2.aspx page embedded in it inside a div element. Now I am unable to hit debugger in the JavaScript included in Page2.aspx

below has the code snippet for understanding. 
Page1.aspx

```
<div id="SomeDiv" style="background-color: white;"></div>
```

Page1.js
//Code to load the new page within a div tag

```
$("#" + 'SomeDiv').load(Page2.aspx, {}, function () {//...  });
```

Now `Page2.Aspx` has JavaScript page `Page2.js`

I am unable to hit debugger on Page2.js.
Is there any solution to do that.

I tried F12 but unable to see Page2 in debugger.

I have only IE explorer.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Type  `debugger;` command in start of your script (As first line in script tag). Then press f12 and refresh your page.

**Also remove check of this:**
Internet Options - Advanced - Disable Script Debugging

Comment: I remember that IE has an option to enable debugger (after press F12). If it is enable now, debugger must works correctly. I use this always. Also check my response update.

Answer (score 0):

Here myself answering my question.
I came to know that there was two debugger processes running in Visual Studio 2015.
Below steps helped me to resole the issue:

- Go to debug tab in VS
- Click on windows
- Select processes and delete the "IE.exe" process and keep the "IIS"
  one

Can also look into this answer:
[the script debugger failed to connect to the target process. Adebugger is already attached](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27127606/the-script-debugger-failed-to-connect-to-the-target-process-adebugger-is-alread/42971132)

Hope this will help others in future.